# Navigation from Folder Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, navigation, directory

I try to load and display pdf and pictures(jpg formatted) as link. I test my code working correctly under `Page_Load` function in Visual Basic class.

```
TextBox2.Text = Me.GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Text & "_1" & ".jpg"
Dim curFile2 As String = "D:\Portal_Test\amir\Uploads\" & TextBox2.Text

If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(curFile2)) Then
    Me.HyperLink1.Visible = True
    Me.HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Uploads\" & TextBox2.Text

Else
    TextBox2.Text = Me.GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Text & "_1" & ".pdf"
    curFile2 = "D:\Portal_Test\amir\Uploads\" & TextBox2.Text

    If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(curFile2)) Then
        Me.HyperLink1.Visible = True
        Me.HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Uploads\" & TextBox2.Text

    Else
        Me.HyperLink1.Visible = False
    End If
End If
```

But I want to load and display it from folder directly not as hyperlink just clicking a button. How can I do that with navigation codes? I try to load that picture(jpg formatted) and pdf files from server's folder directly.

It will be different location from site's location. Such as my site is in the `D:\Portal_Test` but the pdf and jpg's location will be in `D:\604server\DocMan\EENHARCAMA`. How can I handle this loading issue?

Comment: Hey abi, have you tried Process.Start("directory path") and have string as your file name that you want to access?

Comment: How can I use that code block? Can you write visual basic code?

Answer (score 0):

When you start any event you must start the process like:

```
Process.Start("D:\604server\DocMan\EENHARCAMA" + file.extension)
```

Or whererver where your files are.

Comment: Can this code block load image files? I really don't understand. I understood about this Process.Start help to access folders but how can I show this images as link from folder? This images are not located under website's folder.